# C to Python Conversion

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to port some code from C to Python.

I have in C:

```
unsigned char bPort = 7777 ^ 0xCC;
printf("\n %d \n", bPort);
```

Which prints 173

But then in Python

```
bPort = 7777 ^ 0xCC
print(bPort)
```

this prints 7853

Comment: Do you know what the type `char` represents? What is the range of values it can contain?

Comment: I do but how can I represent that in python?

Comment: You probably want `(7777 ^ 0xCC) & 0xff` to mimic the truncation caused by casting..

Comment: Your C code gives me `warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned char bPort = 7777 ^ 0xCC;
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned char bPort = the least significant 8 bits of 7777 ^ 0xCC;
```

`unsigned char` only stores 8 bits.

The same is not true of Python.  I'm not an expert on the numerical types in Python, but I suspect that's either a 32 bit integer or a floating point representation.

To fix it in Python, just mask off the extra bits.

```
bPort = (7777 ^ 0xCC) & 0xff
```

Comment: Python's integers are automagically upgraded to bigints once they surpass the standard 64 bit representation.

Comment: Wouldn't `7777 ^ 0xCC;` be upcasted to int(32) first, then truncated to char?

Comment: I think the effect would be the same.

Comment: The effect here, yes, but I could imagine there are other circumstances where the suggested equivalency fails.

Comment: What about this? 173^140-> 33 in C but in python 173^140 -> 493 also being stored in a unsigned char @RobertHarvey

Comment: @TomasAlves `173^140` in python gives me 33